# How do I push a new project to a new github without it copying into the other

Tags: git, github, repository, project, push

I'm new and very inexperienced, how do you make a new repository in github and how do you populate it only with your new project.

The situation is: I am doing my third ever project. I have been pushing my 2 first projects to github all along except that every subsequent project I push, it just keeps making copies of EVERY project I ever did in every repo I make.

For example, I make repo3 and when I commit to repo3, repo3 will have 3 folders: project1_folder, project2_folder and project3f_folder, although I want repo3 to only have project3_folder and the history associated with only project3_folder

I always do the classical:

```
git init
git add project_folder
git commit -m "blabla"
git remote add origin https://github.com/my_name/repo_of_project#3.git
git push -u origin master
```

In fact, I always add new remotes that point to the new repos I make eg
    git remote add origin2 https://github.com/my_name/repo_of_project#2.git

Thank you in advance, sorry if I am not being coherent in my thoughts. I am so confused and I have searched everywhere

Comment: What folder are you at when you run `git init`? Is it the same folder for all 3 projects? Do you have only one .git folder for all three projects on your local computer?

Comment: I am in a master directory called `/code/` are you saying I need to `git init` in every one of my project folders instead of having just one in the whole folder where I store my code?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one .git folder in the root folder that contains all your projects, that means all your projects are in the same git repository. That's why whenever you push your new project to a new remote repository, all of the projects are pushed.

In order to have a separate git repository for each project, do `git init` in each project folder, which will create a separate .git folder in each project folder.

From the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) :

> If you’re starting to track an existing project in Git, **you need to go to the project’s directory** and type
>
> $ git init
>
> This creates a new subdirectory named .git that contains all of your necessary repository files — a Git repository skeleton.

Comment: Well that makes much more sense, the stupidest questions are the ones I can't always google. It's strange, my prof told me that git init kinda just makes a git folder that is to manage your repositories no matter where it is placed. Thanks a million times